Why is the Sync Progress of the new Cardano Node (9.1.0) always at 100%
I downloaded the new Node (9.1.0) and started it.
cardano-node.exe run --topology ..\share\mainnet\topology.json --config ..\share\mainnet\config.json --database-path ..\share\mainnet\state-preprod --socket-path \\.\pipe\cardano-node-testnet.13880.0

But when i call
cardano-cli query tip --mainnet

i always get a result like this:
{
    "block": 6858011,
    "epoch": 319,
    "era": "Alonzo",
    "hash": "f621ec401a40af473b05550666424b0771cde5a6df968585a0ca6d93aea38fa3",
    "slot": 52781522,
    "slotInEpoch": 336722,
    "slotsToEpochEnd": 95278,
    "syncProgress": "100.00"
}

which can not be correct. Currently we are in Babbage Era, not Alonzo and i a few hours we are in Conway Era.
With the older nodes, the syncProgress worked correcly.
